# Why doesn't my cookie show in input field when set?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a cookie function for setting a cookie in an input field, and a button to save it. when i save it and refresh the page the input field is empty again.

NOTE: i have a jquery dialog and a sticky navigation bar. maybe it overrides the other jquery code somehow.

My jquery code to set the cookie:

```
//set cookie voor de postcode
$(function() {
    $('#go').click(function(){
        $.cookie('postcode', $('#postcode').val());        
    });

    //retrieve the cookie on load if it's not undefined
    if(typeof $.cookie('postcode') !== 'undefined'){
        $('#postcode').val($.cookie('postcode'));
    }
});
```

my function to set the cookie in the input.

```
    <div id="searchbox">
        <div id="search">
        <fieldset>
        <legend><h2>Zoeken in uw regio:</h2></legend>
        <form action="<?= base_url('home/zoekresultaten') ?>">
        <p class="field"><label class="field" for="Naam">Geef een zoekterm op:</label><input type="search" value="" name="postocde" /></p>
        <br />
        <p class="field"><label class="field" for="Naam">Kies hier een categorie:</label><select>
          <option value="0" disabled selected>Alle Categorieën...  </option>
          <option value="1">Categorie1</option>
          <option value="2">Categorie2</option>
          <option value="3">Categorie3</option>
        </select>
        </p>

//my code to set the cookie

        <p class="field"><label class="field" for="Naam">Vul hier uw postcode in:</label><input type="text" id="go" value="" name="search"/></p>

// end of the ocde

        <br />
        <p class="field"><label class="field" for="naam">Kies een afstand:</label><select>
          <option value="0" disabled selected>Afstand...</option>
          <option value="1">5km</option>
          <option value="2">10km</option>
          <option value="3">15km</option>
          <option value="4">20km</option>
          <option value="5">25km</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="go" class="searchbutton" value="Zoek" />
        </form>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
```

I don't know why it isn't working. 
the cookie for hiding the dialog is working fine so the cookie.js file is loaded well.

Thanks.

Comment: which jquery plugin are you using to set cookie ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to note that after setting the cookie you have to reload the page for working of the cookie. Set Cookie and destroy cookie only work after you reload the page at least once after setting and destroying cookie.

Comment: i am reloading the page and it still doesn't do anything so this isn't a good answer.

Comment: there is no code for refreshing the page kindly provide full code

Comment: when i click go the cookie will be set. so what's wrong with that?

Comment: At what stage you are refreshing your page provide that code or else implement after setting cookie to reload the page

Comment: i just posted the button method. i actually have a button to search with a specific postcode. the code looks like this. <input type="text" id="go" value="" name="search"/></p> it submits so it goes to another page first.

Comment: after setting cookie do location.reload(); in jquery

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not populating is because there is no id defined as postcode

either add `id="postcode"` to the postcode input, or use

```
$(function() {
    $('#go').click(function(){
        $.cookie('postcode', $('input[name=postcode]').val());        
    });

    //retrieve the cookie on load if it's not undefined
    if(typeof $.cookie('postcode') !== 'undefined'){
        $('input[name=postcode]').val($.cookie('postcode'));
    }
});
```

Comment: i use php for cookies. and i allready accepted. so no need for other answers.

Comment: @KeesSonnema Please keep in mind that your post will also be read by others, who could benefit from these answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to put autocomplete="off" into input feild.

```
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
```