# Save path to the remote img with cookies?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm using jQuery (1.10.1) + backstretch and [cookies plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).
The idea is to set remote `img` and save the path to the `img using cookies`.

First part wasn't so hard:

```
$("#own").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var own = $("input#img-link").val();
    $(".backstretch img").attr("src", own);
    $.cookie("postcode", $("input[name=postcode]").val());
});

if ( typeof $.cookie("postcode") !== "undefined") {
    $("input[name=postcode]").val($.cookie("postcode"));
}
```

Now I'm a litle bit confused of how I can set my cookies work with it. I've found some example [Example Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472817/why-doesnt-my-cookie-show-in-input-field-when-set):

```
$('#go').click(function(){
    $.cookie('postcode', $('input[name=postcode]').val());        
});

//retrieve the cookie on load if it's not undefined
if(typeof $.cookie('postcode') !== 'undefined'){
    $('input[name=postcode]').val($.cookie('postcode'));
}
```

Cookies now store the data within the browser but how I can push it back from cookies, so on every page refresh img will be loaded from cookies?

Comment: how is it complicated?

Comment: I ve tried few times and my mission failed. I ve no problems with the cookie plugin but I'm quite lost with 'input[name=postcode]'

Comment: can you share your markup and what you tried

Comment: `'input[name=postcode]'` means an input field with name `postcode`

Comment: Well yes, that was very dumb of me. Cookies now store the data within the browser but how I can push it back from cookies, so on every page refresh img will be loaded from cookies?

Comment: instead of adding the code as a comment edit the question

Comment: Done. Well yes now the data stored within the cookie, however it's not how I thought it will work. I want to save the data from input field into the cookie and then I guess I need to load it back on every page load so the img will already exist as a background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting your image's property, you are setting some other elements properties

```
$("#own").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var own = $("input#img-link").val();
    $(".backstretch img").attr("src", own);
    $.cookie("backstretch-img", own);
});

var own = $.cookie("backstretch-img");
if ( typeof own !== "undefined") {
    $(".backstretch img").attr("src", own);
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is the thing which I was trying to achieve all night. Thank You Sir!

Comment: I know I need to learn html and jquery harder. Will do my best. Just started a couple of months ago.